# why does my java code print out [ ] when I insert 2 numbers in it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forA1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String []num = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
            int m = Integer.parseInt(num[1]);

            while(n != 0){
                // initialize the queue
                Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                queue.clear();
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                    queue.add(i);

                //int res = 0;
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
                        queue.add(queue.remove());
                    queue.remove();
                }
                //System.out.println(res);
                //System.out.println(res);

                System.out.print(queue);

                String []num2 = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                n = Integer.parseInt(num2[0]);
                m = Integer.parseInt(num2[1]);
            }
        }
}
```

When I insert 2 numbers, it will print out [].Can some please explain to me why this happens, I'm a student, so I apologize if I'm asking a question that is easy for others.

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Let's look at your logic... `while (!queue.isEmpty())` --- while the loop is not empty.... your very next statement prints the empty queue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the queue, but since you have the condition `while (!queue.isEmpty())`, no matter what you do inside the loop *(unless you have some kind of* `break` *logic, thanks to @Andy's comment)*  you'll either never leave it (i.e. an infinite loop), or get an empty queue after it.

If you change from

```
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) { 
                for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
                    queue.add(queue.remove());
                queue.remove();
            }
```

to

```
            for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
                queue.add(queue.remove());
            queue.remove();
```

You will be able to see some non-empty output (given appropriate `m` and `n` values).

Comment: "no matter what you do inside the loop you'll either never leave it (i.e. an infinite loop), or get an empty queue after " what if there is a `break` in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Since you aren't decrementing the value of 'n', it's an infinite loop so far proper input is provided viz. the values of 'n' & 'm':-

```
    while(n != 0){
...
// lines of code
String []num2 = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(num2[0]);
            m = Integer.parseInt(num2[1]);
}
```

Secondly, for your question- "*When I insert 2 numbers, it will print out []. Can some please explain to me why this happens?*" Actually, you have written a block of code in your program as below:-

```
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++)
                    queue.add(queue.remove());
                queue.remove();
            }
```

Last 2 lines of this block of code (just before closing braces) have counter effect on the queue. It would make your queue empty (You can check the same by putting - "`System.out.println(queue);`" before & after this while loop, you will understand more clearly by doing the same). As a result, you are getting "[]" as your output (in the console window) which is empty Queue !!

PS:- In Java, we always use "`System.out.println();`" to debug wherever we wish to understand the flow of the program.